# Can't figure out a solution to this regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following list of strings:

```
$list = array(
 'c1' => '{sometext...} 1tb hdd 1tb hdd {sometext...}'
 'c2' => '{sometext...} 1tb hdd 1tb {sometext...}',
 'c3' => '{sometext...} hdd 1tb hdd 1tb {sometext...}',
 'c4' => '{sometext...} hdd 1tb hdd 1tb hdd {sometext...}'
);
```

and the following regular expression which should run on all strings, and if a match is found, return `true` otherwise, return `false`.

`/(?<!hdd\s)(\dtb hdd \dtb){1,}(?!\shdd)/`

As of now, my result set looks something like this:

```
'c1' => false,
'c2' => true,
'c3' => false,
'c4' => false
```

However, for the correct result, would be, to mark `c4` as `true` instead. How could I change my regex, to achieve the desired result?

**USE CASE**: the use case for this would be, to correctly identify ambigous attributes in product title naming. In case1 and case3, it is easily decidable which capacity belongs to which storage device, however in the other two cases, it is not programatically decidable, because there is a `hdd` without a capacity value.

**NOTE**: Counting the number of `hdd` instances in the string is not a good solution, as in the `{sometext...}` part of the string, other instances of the text may appear as different kind of noise.

Comment: only c4 or (c4 AND c2)?

Comment: Maybe `preg_grep('~(?<=(hdd\s)|)\dtb hdd \dtb(?(1)(?=\shdd)|(?!\shdd))~', $list)`? See [the PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/EG5mC).

Comment: I'd first think of something like [`(?:hdd \dtb|\dtb hdd)(*SKIP)(*F)|hdd|\dtb`](https://regex101.com/r/mnfLIe/1) (not sure, if on the right track).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=(hdd\s)|)\dtb hdd \dtb(?(1)(?=\shdd)|(?!\shdd))
(?:hdd\s+\dtb hdd \dtb(?!\s+hdd)|(?<!hdd\s)\dtb hdd \dtb\s+hdd)(*SKIP)(*F)|\dtb hdd \dtb
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/wEv3hx/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/wEv3hx/2/).

*Details #1*:

- `(?<=(hdd\s)|)` - checks if there is `hdd`+whitespace (captured into Group 1) or empty string immediately to the left of the current location
- `\dtb hdd \dtb` - matches digit + `tb hdd`  + digit + `tb`
- `(?(1)(?=\shdd)|(?!\shdd))` - if Group 1 value is not null, make sure there is a whitespace and `hdd` immediately to the right of the current location, else, makes sure this pattern cannot be found at the same location.

*Details #2*:

- `(?:hdd\s+\dtb hdd \dtb(?!\s+hdd)|(?<!hdd\s)\dtb hdd \dtb\s+hdd)(*SKIP)(*F)` - matches the `hdd\s+\dtb hdd \dtb` pattern that is not immediately followed with 1+ whitespaces + `hdd` or a `\dtb hdd \dtb\s+hdd` that is not immediately preceded with `hdd` + whitespace, fails these matches and goes on to search for the next match from the failure location
- `|` - or
- `\dtb hdd \dtb` - matches digit, `tb hdd` , digit, `tb`.

See the [PHP demo](https://regex101.com/r/mnfLIe/1):

```php
$list = array(
 'c1' => '{sometext...} 1tb hdd 1tb hdd {sometext...}',
 'c2' => '{sometext...} 1tb hdd 1tb {sometext...}',
 'c3' => '{sometext...} hdd 1tb hdd 1tb {sometext...}',
 'c4' => '{sometext...} hdd 1tb hdd 1tb hdd {sometext...}'
);
print_r(preg_grep('~(?<=(hdd\s)|)\dtb hdd \dtb(?(1)(?=\shdd)|(?!\shdd))~', $list));
// => Array
//   (
//     [c2] => {sometext...} 1tb hdd 1tb {sometext...}
//     [c4] => {sometext...} hdd 1tb hdd 1tb hdd {sometext...}
//   )
```